# Dimension of matrices with entries $a_{ij} = a_{rs}$ with $i+j = r+s$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $H_n$ be the space of all $n \times n$ matrices $A = (a_{ij})$ with entries in $\Bbb{R}$ satisfying $a_{ij} = a_{rs}$ whenever $i+j = r+s \; (i,j,r,s = 1, 2, \ldots, n)$. Then what is the dimension of $H_n$, as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$?

I think the matrices must be symmetric, and so dimension will be $\frac{n^2 -n}{2} + n$.
Am I right?

Comment: These matrices will be symmetric: because $i + j = j + i$, we always have $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$. Except when $n < 3$, however, not all symmetric matrices will be of this form. In the case $n = 3$, matrices in your class satisfy $a_{13} = a_{22}$, but this does not hold for all symmetric matrices.

Comment: The matrices will be symmetric but that's not the end of the story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  Here is a table of the sums $i+j$ for $n=5$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{array}
$$

For each possible sum of indices, you have to specify a real number.  So, in this case, $\dim H_5 = 9$.  Can you see how this generalizes?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**.  To fully specify such a matrix, you just need to give the value of $a_{ij}$ for every possible value of $i+j$.  How many possible values of $i+j$ are there?